# Filter array by range of numbers

Tags: swift, filter, range

I have an array with a bunch of numbers:

```
let array = [0,10,24,3,4,5,67,7,8,9,2,1,34,6,7,2,4,6,8,0,303,444]
```

How do I get all the values between 5 and 10 for example? There has to be a better way then a for iteration through all the numbers or?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `filter` for this with different alternatives:

1: `let filtered = array.filter({ $0 >= 5 && $0 <= 10 })`

2: `let filtered = array.filter({ 5..<11 ~= $0 })`

3: `let filtered = array.filter((5...10).contains)`

All will get you `[10, 5, 7, 8, 9, 6, 7, 6, 8]`

Comment: You can use is in range operator ~=, try this let filtered = array.filter({ 6..<10 ~= $0 }) I think it's much nicer syntax, and 6<10 may be replaced with parameter of type range.

Comment: Or `array.filter((5...10).contains)`

Comment: Yes guys, added these to the answer since they are good alternative solutions. Thanks.

Comment: It's personal preference but I much prefer only using `<` or `<=` and never `>` because it makes it much easier to read... `5 <= $0 && $0 <= 10`

Comment: Definitely avoid `1.`, it makes it fare too easy to mix up the order or the exact signs. I agree @Fogmeister's is nicer, but I would still avoid it in favor of `3.`

Answer (score 0):

```
    let filtered = array.filter {
      $0 >= 5 && $0 <= 10
    }
```